# C++ (x == 1) the same as (x & 1)

Tags: c++

I recently saw an open source program where somebody used

```
if (x & 1){
```

Where x was an int. I tried this out myself and as far as I can see this has the same effect us using

```
if (x == 1){
```

As far as I understand the `&` symbol is used for referencing objects, but here it seems to be used as an equal to operator.

Am I mistaken in thinking these are the same thing? Or are there different reasons to use each one?

Comment: They are not equivalent at all, try with `x = 3`

Comment: `x & 1` is true for any positive odd integer, not just 1.

Comment: `x & 1` is a [bitwise operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Bitwise_logic_operators). It's the AND operator applied to each bit of `x` with the matching bit of `1`.

Comment: @chepner: And negative odd integers (in two's complement or sign-magnitude representation) or negative even integers (in one's complement)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: *bitwise*, not *size*

Comment: If `x` is indeed of a native integer type (like `int`) *and* `x` is equal to `1`, then yes `x == 1` and `x & 1` will give the same *result* (but they are not the same). And you should probably take some time to [read a few good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) about the *bitwise operators*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude They'll give you the same result for only certain values, which can be said of many unrelated functions.

Comment: `((x & 1) && !(x & ~1))` would give the same result as `(x == 1)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The statement `x & 1` uses the *bitwise and operator*, in other words, comparing those two values on a binary level, bit by bit. The `==` comparison is used to test *equivalence*, in other words, all bits are identical.

What `x & 1` does is check that the bit in the 1s place is set to 1. For any unsigned `x`, any odd value will show up as true since any odd value has that bit set.

Answer (score 1):

The `&` operator here is the bitwise and. It takes the binary representation of both operands and `and`s each pair of bits into the result. For example: (assume the following numbers are all binary representations)

```
10010111 & 00111011
```

would result in:

```
00010011
```

It effectively can be used to "check" to see if a particular set of bits are "set" in an operand since, if they are, the result would be non-zero (i.e. true enough to pass an `if` statement).

Given that, this code is likely *not* checking wither `x == 1` but rather, whether the first bit of `x` has been set.